# looking for a start in solidity

Tags: truffle-migration, truffle-contract, truffle-deployment, truffle-compile

I am totally new to the Solidity Programing. I was working on NodeJS, express and mongoDB. Few days ago I started working on blockchain. I have to write the API'S for contracts. We are using truffle and tronweb. Is there any simple project or tutorial available which gives me idea of how this whole thing works.

Comment: The question mentioned by Ismael is indeed a duplicate - consider also the official Solidity Intro, it's quite good: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest the udemy course: [Ethereum and Solidity The Complete Developers Guide](https://www.udemy.com/course/ethereum-and-solidity-the-complete-developers-guide/)?
It's far from a complete developers guide but it was a nice introduction to developing smart contract enabled web applications.

The course is like 2 years old, it does not cover truffle and there are some quirks(none that couldn't be solved). Nevertheless the instructor was super pedagogic and i enjoyed the course!